# Skip html line in Twig

Tags: html, twig, twig-extension

I have not used Twig before and now rise wit problem that I need skip full line in twig as it is

My html is

```
<h4 class="title">{{ 'publish' | translate }}</h4>
```

In my index

```
require_once('lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    //'cache' => 'cache',
    'auto_reload' => true
));
```

When I render html I get Twig error because of translate. I need advice how to tell twig skip these line as it is not to change any symbol in my html (maybe with tag "translate")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add fake filter `translate`

```
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('translate', function($v) {return $v;}));
```

Comment: these line works and no error but return only "publish" not {{ 'publish' | translate }}

Comment: than try to use `{% verbatim %}..{% endverbatim %}` http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

Comment: If you want to keep html tags, you can make this way `{% set tmp %}{% verbatim %}....{% endverbatim %}{% endset %}{{ tmp|escape|nl2br }}`

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to keep html tags in twig coming from symfony controller or php, you can use twig filters like raw or escape:

`<h4 class="title">{{ variable|raw }}</h4>` or `<h4 class="title">{{ variable|escape }}</h4>.`

You have also autoescape tag

```
{% autoescape 'html' %}
```

You put your code containing html `{% endautoescape %}`

Be sure that those filters or tags can raise security issue.